# Docusign API returns Unauthorized Client

Tags: php, docusignapi

I am getting 400 bad request with docusign production account while accessing access token.
I am using these values while making call.

```
URL: https://account.docusign.com/oauth/token
Header: Authorization:'Combination of integration key and secret key';
Body: grant_type:authorization_code,code: 'Which I am getting from login callback';
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Furst make sure "Authorization" in the header is

> Basic BASE64_COMBINATION_OF_INTEGRATION_AND_SECRET_KEY

not just combination of both

Referring to DocuSign Auth Code Grant [guide](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/authcode/authcode-get-token/)

> The obtained authorization code is only viable for two minutes. If more then two minutes pass between obtaining the authorization code and attempting to exchange it for an access token, the operation will fail.

If this is not the case, please open a support case through our [support portal](https://support.docusign.com/) as we may need specific account information